# How to use stacked segment in Semantic UI?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

A Semantic UI segment can be formatted to show it contains multiple pages

```
<div class="ui stacked segment">
 <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada .</p>
</div>
```

How do you actually use this, any practical example? How do you show the other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style is only a visual effect. There is no way to create content for other pages at least you use javascript or jquery.